# Two backslash in my URL in google analytics

Tags: url, google-analytics

I have a problem with the backslash in my URL in google analytics account.
In my results and when I click on the URL to see it, it opens it like that example.com//example/example...

Also, I have a sub domain, how can I see both of the results:
lp.example.com
and
example.com

Answer (score 0):

Check the domain name you entered in the view settings (Website's URL).

You can use the `host name` to see domains in reports using it as secondary dimension.

Comment: Hi there, I have. It was the first thing I did. In one of the views it was with /, but in the other not. For all views it make that mistake.